# D3 v5 zoom control bubble map json asynchron data

Tags: json, d3.js, zooming

I have read quite a few tutorials on the d3 bubble map with zoom but I can't seem to find a solution in v5 to my problem. Which is have a map with zoom but not change the radius of the bubbles. With the new CORS restrictions you cannot load local file. So I use php and some remote depository to get my data through json and work with it. In consequence the code is segmented and it is hard to get data outside the asynchronous function. Like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916743/stop-zooming-of-bubbles-in-d3-world-map) for example didn't work. I have tried to use complex viewports etc but I am still limited by the presence of these functions calling data and partitioning the code. Any help is welcome.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.1.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      path {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 0.1px;
        fill: lightblue;
      }
      #map-holder {
        width: 100%;
        height: 640px;

      }
      circle {
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: green;
        opacity: 0.2;
      }
      svg {
        background-color: navy;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/3.0.2/topojson.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-holder"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      const width =  800;
      const height = 640;

      var projection = d3.geoMercator()
       .center ([-5,58.5])
       .scale([6000]);

      var path = d3.geoPath()
          .projection(projection);

      var format = d3.format(",.5f");

      var svg = d3.select("#map-holder")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
          .on("click", reset);

     var g = svg.append("g");

/// zoom management
     const zoom = d3.zoom()
         .scaleExtent([0.05,10])
         .on("zoom", zoomed);

     function zoomed() {
               const {transform} = d3.event;
               g.attr("transform", transform);
               g.attr("stroke-width", 1 / transform.k);
//not working               g.selectAll("circle")
//not working               .attr("r",radius / transform.k);


             }
      function clicked(d) {
                   const [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]] = path.bounds(d);
                   d3.event.stopPropagation();
                   svg.transition().duration(750).call(
                     zoom.transform,
                     d3.zoomIdentity
                       .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
                       .scale(Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max((x1 - x0) / width, (y1 - y0) / height)))
                       .translate(-(x0 + x1) / 2, -(y0 + y1) / 2),
                     d3.mouse(svg.node())
                   );
                 }
      function reset() {
             svg.transition().duration(750).call(
               zoom.transform,
               d3.zoomIdentity,
               d3.zoomTransform(svg.node()).invert([width / 2, height / 2])
             );
           }
// Legend management
     const legend = svg.append("g")
           .attr("fill", "#777")
           .attr("transform", "translate(750,20)")
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .style("font", "8px sans-serif")
         .selectAll("g").data([1e1, 1e2, 1e3])
         .join("g");
     legend.append("circle")
       .attr("class","city-circle")
       .attr("fill", "none")
       .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
       .attr("cy", function(d){
         return [3*format(Math.log(d))]
               })
       .attr("r", function(d){
         return [3*format(Math.log(d))]
               });
   legend.append("text")
       .attr("y", function(d){
         return [6*format(Math.log(d))]
               })
       .attr("dy", "1.3em")
       .text(d3.format(".1s"))

// data call
   d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-10m.json")
     .then(function(topology){

      d3.json("https://www.plasticatbay.org/ChartBal/DataWeights.php").then(function(dataCircles){

     g.selectAll("path")
     .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.countries)
      .features)
     .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", path)

      g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(dataCircles)
      .join("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){
          return projection([format(d.Longit), format(d.Lat)])[0];
            })
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return projection([format(d.Longit), format(d.Lat)])[1];
            })
        .attr("r", function(d){
          return [3*format(Math.log(d.Weights))]
                        })
      .append("title")
        .text(d => d.Beach);
      });
    });
      svg.call(zoom);
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you are trying to scale the circles on zoom (I'm not sure if I am reading your question right). I see two lines commented saying not working, that show an intent, and am commenting on that; however, this would be the same comment for d3v4,d3v3 & d3v5 which is why I am not sure I understand. In the zoom function, we could define the radius the same was as you started with and then divide by transform.k:  `g.selectAll("circle").attr("r", function(d){ return 3*format(Math.log(d.Weights))/transform.k  })`. The circles stay the same size when zooming for me  - though the stroke changes...

Comment: Thanks! I really don't understand myself as I could never get d.Weight to return anything out of the get.JSON function. Thanks for clearing this up for me...

Comment: I think my mistake was to not initialise the circles first in the Json function. I was either generating in the json function or in the zoom one whereas I needed both I think.